# How to read a message from Kafka topic on demand

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

How can I read a message from Kafka topic on demand. I have the topic name, offsetId, PartitionID, using these three params, how can i retrieve a specific message from Kafka Topic. Is it possible using Spring Kafka ?
I am using spring boot 2.2.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 4):

- create consumer
- assign the topic/partition
- seek
- poll for one record
- close consumer

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So64759726Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So64759726Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(ConsumerFactory<String, String> cf) {
        return args -> {
            try (Consumer<String, String> consumer = cf.createConsumer()) {
                TopicPartition tp = new TopicPartition("so64759726", 0);
                consumer.assign(Collections.singleton(tp));
                consumer.seek(tp, 2);
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
                System.out.println(records.iterator().next().value());
            }
        };
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=1
```

**UPDATE**

Since this answer was posted, the `KafkaTemplate` now has `receive()` methods for on-demand consumption.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#kafka-template-receive

```java
ConsumerRecord<K, V> receive(String topic, int partition, long offset);

ConsumerRecord<K, V> receive(String topic, int partition, long offset, Duration pollTimeout);

ConsumerRecords<K, V> receive(Collection<TopicPartitionOffset> requested);

ConsumerRecords<K, V> receive(Collection<TopicPartitionOffset> requested, Duration pollTimeout);
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. I assume i do not need to do any of those container creation configurations which we do for a generic KafkaListener. Will this be sufficient to pull a particular message. If i need to configure SSL params, where do i do that

Comment: Correct; what I show above is the complete application. SSL settings go in `application.properties/application.yml` as normal. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#integration-properties - scroll down to the `spring.kafka.ssl...` properties.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Is it possible to use ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory instead of consumerFactory to create the consumer instances?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense; the container factory creates containers; those containers subsequently use the consumer factory to create consumers for message-driven consumption. By the way, after this answer was posted, the `KafkaTemplate` now has `receive()` operations for on-demand consumption. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#kafka-template-receive

Comment: This seems bit counterintuitive to me. Kafkatemplate needs a "producerfactory" in constructor but helps in message "consumption" with receive() API ? Am i missing or misunderstanding something here ?

Comment: For the vast majority of users, the template is used for publishing only. To use the receive methods you need to also add a consumer factory (`setConsumerFactory()`). This functionality was added here for consistency with other templates in the Spring portfolio that also support send and receive operations; `JmsTemplate`, `RabbitTemplate`, etc.